# Get certain value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 
  [12] => Array ( 
    [termimages] => Array ( 
      [0] => 58
      [1] => 57
      [2] => 56 
    ) 
  )
)
```

My result with print_r from $meta.

How can I set a value "12" from array to variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you have posted is not a valid array

Comment: as you can see - there is nothing assigned to 0. And it is what I'm talking about

Comment: Yes indeed.:/ How to get second key from first array?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to get the key of the first member of an array that is the first member of `$meta`?

```
$keys = array_keys($meta[0]);
$key = $keys[0];
```

---

You've updated your question:

> How to get second key from first array?

I.e., in this case, how to retrieve `$meta`'s second key. The technique is exactly the same as above:

```
$keys = array_keys($meta);
$key = $keys[1];
```

(And, if and when [array dereferencing comes online](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html), this will be able to be shortened to `$key = array_keys($meta)[1];`, but alas not yet.)

Comment: This one looks like  is working
$keys = array_keys($meta);
$key = $keys[1];

Answer (score 1):

$array[0][12] = 'string';

Or do u wanna extract the array keys?

Comment: Seems like more key not value. Pardon my lack of knowledge about arrays.

Comment: In a loop go: foreach ($array as $key => $value)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set a value "12" from array to variable?

Since there is no value `"12"` anywhere, I assume you mean the key `"12"`, which has the value of:

```
Array ( 
    [termimages] => Array ( 
      [0] => 58
      [1] => 57
      [2] => 56 
    ) 
)
```

To assign it to a variable simply do:

```
$variable = $meta["12"];
```

prints:

```
print_r($variable);

Array
(
    [termimages] => Array
        (
            [0] => 58
            [1] => 57
            [2] => 56
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you every one for helping me! I found another solution not related to array.